# How do i Remove mobile jQuery styling from RadioButtonlist Control?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, radiobuttonlist

I need to disable the styling for Asp.net radio button list control when page load start. i have tried

```
data-role='none'

<table border="0" onclick="IsChecked();" data-role="none" class="" id="RBTruetype">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="217,1" name="RBTruetype" id="RBTruetype_0"><label for="RBTruetype_0" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-radio-off ui-btn-up-undefined"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">True</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-radio-off"></span></span></label></div></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="218,0" name="RBTruetype" id="RBTruetype_1" checked="checked"><label for="RBTruetype_1" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-undefined ui-radio-on"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">False</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-radio-on"></span></span></label></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

above is my rendered control. now can someone help me to disable the styling for this control only?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `data-role="none"` attribute on the `input` element:

```
<input type="radio" data-role="none" value="218,0" name="RBTruetype" id="RBTruetype_1" checked="checked">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/bmP8G/

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, here is another example that swaps out the styled radio button for the unstlyed version.  Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/bmP8G/1/

Comment: Appreciated but i am binding that radio button list at run-time, so how will i do that? its very annoying please help.

Comment: '<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBTruetype" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="fakeselect" data-role="none" onclick="IsChecked();" runat="server">
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>'

Comment: above is my page level control i have specified data-role='none' but it didn't recognize to the radio button.

Comment: see example in update.  Could you just not bind it at runtime?  You may need to provide more code if you want a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like: `myRadioList.InputAttributes.Add("data-role", "none")`

Comment: Yeah Shanabus i tried that also. but now i had resolved this issue by adding attribute on data bound method of radio button list and onclick event added at runtime which calls javascript function with value as parameter then assigned the value to hidden variable. So i got my solution. Thanks all of you for your time.